# PHP cURL with SS validation

Tags: php, validation, curl

I have some working cURL scripts but have been relying on the remote server for SS validation. I want to add some validation to our cURL scripts so that if they aren't filled out correctly the request won't get sent. I have client side JS validation, but want to duplicate with SS validation. 
Here is an example of my cURL script:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://remoteserver.com/POST.svc/Foo';
$Field1 = $_POST["Field1"];
//other input data

$fields = array(
'Field1'=>urlencode($Field1),
//other input data
);

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'& ');

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

echo $output;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Can I just create an if/else statement like:

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['Field1']))) {
echo "Error";
die();
} else {
$url = 'https://remoteserver.com/POST.svc/Foo';
$Field1 = $_POST["Field1"];
//other input data

$fields = array(
'Field1'=>urlencode($Field1),
//other input data
);

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'& ');

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

echo $output;
curl_close($ch);
}
```

I have ajax stuff that is displayed if the return is "Error". This can't be that easy, is it?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just returning 'Error', why not return some useful stuff? A PHP structure such as

```
$request_status = array(
    'error' => 1,
    'error_msg' => 'Form was not completed properly'
    'error_details' => array(
        0 => 'Name field not completed',
        1 => 'Invalid state specified',
        2 => 'Password1 and Password 2 do not match'
    )
)

echo json_encode($request_status);
```

would be of far more use. Your client-side ajax code can simply look for the 'error' parameter in there and either go "Hey, it worked!" or do further based on the error_details you supplied, such as highlighting the form fields that weren't completed correctly.

This also allows you to send back other types of error messages as well, such as saying "hey, the place we're CURLing your form to isn't responding" and the like.

Comment: That's awesome, Ill integrate this as well. Right now I do display the "message" that is returned from the remote server with the ajax validation. Is the original if/else format correct? I apologize, Im not as well versed in PHP as I am in JS/CSS/XHTML etc and really appreciate your help

Comment: Sure, handing an AJAX submission is no different than handling a regular "the user clicked 'submit' on the form" as far as field validation goes. basically have a set of if/then/else checks to validate the fields that need validation, and then proceed (do curl) or abort (return the error data) .

Comment: Sorry to be so thick. so what I had in the second code box would work? if the field(s) are empty echo json_encode... (will add the function you provided) else - all the curl code?

Comment: Yep. And then after the curl stuff completes, you can still return the above type of data, but making it `error = 0` and `error_msg = form submitted ok` type thing.

Comment: Ill have to do some research on the $request_status.. and error = 0 and error_msg = form submitted ok stuff - I don't quite grasp that completely as far as how/where it would go in my script. I don't know if it will conflict with showing their server's response as I'm doing now.

Comment: After the curl stuff goes, you can do `$response = ('error' => curl_errno(), 'error_message' => $output)` as a basic response - that'd still pass back the other server's status, wrapped within your own error-type object.

Comment: OK, I would really like to incorporate your method. currently the ajax method is based on a table the remote server returns, searches for the second row, second column. If that cell contains "True" it displays success message/else it displays <my code> + message + </mycode>. With this in place, if something passes client validation but not serverside and the cURL isn't even sent, no error msg is displayed. This is problematic to me. Does that make sense? I'd be happy to share code somehwere I can format it better

Comment: so you fetch a table from the remote server, pass it back to the ajax client, javascript searches that table for the 2,2 cell, then displays a message?

Comment: Yes, I submit the data via cURL, a response is generated from the remote server and passed back to my page. The jQuery ajax function searches the table for the 2,2 cell and based on the return message the appropriate div with either the success msg or error message + message (error msg from the remote server) is displayed.

Comment: seems to me it'd be easier to have PHP do the parsing and just send back a simple "yes"/"no" type response to your javascript.